# Rails 5 - image is not loading in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, assets

Hi have build my own simple profile and am maintaining my code in Heroku, but the images in not get loading Heroku. Here i share my production set-up.

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
```

I am using ruby 2.3.0 and rails 5.1.

Comment: There is a lot of question with problem like this one, have you tried something?

Comment: image means profile uploaded by user or static images from asset folder ?

Comment: Where are the images located - in `public` or in `assets`? How are the images included in the views, via its name or do you use the asset pipeline? Did you try to load the images directly by their URLs, did that work?

Comment: It is static images which is present in assets.

Comment: I included my images as assets/image.png

Comment: <%= image_tag('image.png') %> is working fine in local ? if yes try to precompile in heroku and  set config.assets.compile = true

Comment: do you have `gem 'rails_12factor'` in Gemfile?

Comment: Yes i included gem 'rails_12factor'. If i set config.assets.compile = true, the image is loading the css is not loading.

Comment: And this is what i have did in application.rb config.serve_static_assets = true
    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
    config.assets.enabled = true
    config.assets.version = '1.0'

Comment: Setting assets.compile=true is a major performance hit on production.  Instead, make sure to run "bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production", then commit it with git then push to heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails 5.x apps it is not necessary to require '**rails_12factor**' gem because its functions are now included be default: 
https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor#rails-5

Just tested and image (*/app/assets/images/image.jpg*) was loaded correctly with default settings in production configuration:

```
config.assets.compile = false

config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
end
```

and without this options (in any config):

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.digest = true
```

Comment: Thanks Vladv, http://myoutline.herokuapp.com/ this is my website URL. You can see now the images is loading but the font awesome icons is not loading.

Comment: It is working fine now. I have enabled config.assets.compile = true in production.rb and do precompile in production now it is working fine.